# UISearchBar subview of UITableViewHeader?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I want to add a UISearchBar to a UITableView that already has a header view. When I try and add the search bar to the existing header view it works until I tap on it, at which point I get `The view hierarchy is not prepared for the constraint`, which appears to be because the search bar is not a direct subview of the tableview so when the UISearchController tries to update the constraints it can't.

The only way around this that I've found is making the table view header the search bar, then everything works fine, but of course then I lose the other views that were already in the header view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get around this behavior, I put my search bar in a container `UIView`.  Apply the constraints to this container view and use an autoresizing mask for the search bar within the container.

```
// Configure header view
UIView *headerView = ...
...

// Create container view for search bar
UIView *searchBarContainer = [UIView new];
searchBarContainer.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[searchBarContainer addSubview:self.searchBar];
[headerView addSubview:searchBarContainer];
self.searchBar.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

// Apply constraints involving searchBarContainer
[headerView addConstraint: ...];
...

// Then add header to table view
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView;
```

Comment: Wow, thank you! It took me days of searching and trying various workarounds until finding your post. Since I am using UISearchController I have a weird problem where the UISearchBar is added to searchBarContainer, but then when I check in viewWillAppear it's no longer in there, so I have to manually add it again. Currently fighting against initial frame weirdness after re-adding the UISearchBar as a subview in the container, but this is definitely in the right direction.

Comment: You may have to add this in viewWillAppear: if (self.searchBarContainerView.subviews.count == 0) {
        [self.searchBarContainerView addSubview:self.searchController.searchBar];
        // also gotta fix the frame height
        CGRect frame = self.searchBarContainerView.frame;
        frame.size.height = 44.0f;
        self.searchBarContainerView.frame = frame;
    }