# Swift: iOS The view hierarchy is not prepared for the constraint while animating UISearchBar

Tags: swift, autolayout

I have done a lot of research on the "The view hierarchy..." problem and I believe I've tried every iteration of solution that is offered on SO. I think my problem must be a little different (or I'm missing something obvious) in that updating the constraints is failing during animation during `searchBarTextDidBeginEditing`

I am trying to add a `UISearchBar` directly to the main `UIView`. I set `inactiveSearchBarConstraintY` as a global variable as I am going to modify it later. I accomplish this with the following (makes no difference in viewDidLoad vs viewDidAppear):

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.tableView.dataSource = self
    self.tableView.delegate = self

    self.resultSearchController = ({
        let controller = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        controller.searchResultsUpdater = self
        controller.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        controller.searchBar.sizeToFit()
        controller.searchBar.frame.size.width = self.view.frame.size.width
        controller.searchBar.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
        self.view.addSubview(controller.searchBar)

        let searchBarConstraintX = NSLayoutConstraint(item: controller.searchBar, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        self.view.addConstraint(searchBarConstraintX)

        self.inactiveSearchBarConstraintY = NSLayoutConstraint(item: controller.searchBar, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, multiplier: 1, constant: 300)
        self.view.addConstraint(self.inactiveSearchBarConstraintY)

        let searchBarConstraintWidth = NSLayoutConstraint(item: controller.searchBar, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 300)
        self.view.addConstraint(searchBarConstraintWidth)

        let searchBarConstraintHeight = NSLayoutConstraint(item: controller.searchBar, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 100)
        self.view.addConstraint(searchBarConstraintHeight)
        controller.searchBar.delegate = self 

        return controller
    })()
```

Like I said, this loads fine. The searchbar is added to `self.view` and at the distance indicated by `inactiveSearchBarConstraintY`

My problem comes when I try to edit the search bar. When I touch the searchbar, it and the tableview should both move up (different amounts, which is why they aren't attached).

```
    func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    self.resultSearchController.active = true;

    self.inactiveSearchBarConstraintY.constant = 0 //<-- crashes with or without this
    self.tableViewConstraintY.constant = 200

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.7, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveLinear, animations: {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: { finished in
            self.resultSearchController.active = true
    })
}
```

With this code, the app crashes when I touch the search bar.

IN FACT, the app crashes without any of this in the function! As follows:

```
func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
self.resultSearchController.active = true;
}
```

This is the failure message

```
The view hierarchy is not prepared for the constraint: <NSLayoutConstraint:0x78f9dd40 UISearchBar:0x78e10a80.leading == UIView:0x78e39380.leading>

When added to a view, the constraint's items must be descendants of that view (or the view itself). This will crash if the constraint needs to be resolved before the view hierarchy is assembled. Break on -[UIView _viewHierarchyUnpreparedForConstraint:] to debug.

2015-09-03 07:03:27.108 MyApp[24606:415328] *** Assertion failure in -[UIView _layoutEngine_didAddLayoutConstraint:roundingAdjustment:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3347.44/NSLayoutConstraint_UIKitAdditions.m:560
```

Comment: A workaround is proposed here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27512738/uisearchbar-subview-of-uitableviewheader . It isn't perfect but it works.

Comment: Thanks. This almost works. It no longer fails with the error above, but now the searchBar jumps to the final position of the animateWithDuration while the searchBarContainer slowly moves to its final position. Any idea there?